# Maximus iv extreme z with 8gb Hyperx fury modules error 55

Tags: memory, motherboard

I got ram upgrade from 16gb (4x4gb hyperx) to 32gb (4x8gb HyperX HX318C10FB/8). I have Maximus iv extreme z and i7 2600.

When I install new modules I recive error 55 on the motherboard (memory not installed). I googled for solutions and upadated my bios, reset CMOS but nothing works.

As I understood info from documentation, those modules should be compatible with the motherboard.

Is there solution for this? Am I maybe using incompatible modules?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you verified your using the current firmware?  Have you verified each module works in another PC?  We need more information to help.

Comment: I got brand new modules and I dont have oportunity to test them on other PC.  What exactly to you mean by current firmware?

Comment: The revision of your BIOS firmware.  Are you running the current version?

Comment: Yes I updated BIOS to the most current version. This was my first try. Since it didnt work, I tried with CMOS reseting, but that didnt work either. Now I am at the point when I have no ideas...

Comment: Have you tried just booting with 2 modules?\

Comment: I tried booting with 2, and with one. Didnt work.

Comment: Is the memory your using on the 8GB QVL list from ASUS?

Comment: actually, it isn't. But QVL was created before the release date of ram. I am not finding any newer QVL than july 2011.

Comment: What is the part number for the 4GB modules.  The 8GB modules are 1.5 volts modules, if the 4GB modules are not 1.5 volts, I suspect you simply don't have compatible memory.  Of course given they are from the same product line I doubt that is the case, which tells me, the modules might simply be DOA.

Comment: 4gb are 1.65V KHX1600C9D3/4GX. Do you mean by DOA that they may be literally dead on arrival?

Comment: Yes;  That is exactly what I mean.

Comment: Should I return those? Could I possibly damage them with improper BIOS setings that remained from previous configuration?

Comment: You made no mention of your system even attempting to POST.  So it is unlikely you caused damage to the modules.

Comment: Is there any option more to test before I return modules?

Comment: Based on your initial response, to my first comment, you don't have another PC you can use to test the modules.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I solved this problem.
Problem was in one dead module.
Unfortunately, dead module was the first module I tried, so I wasn't sure it is dead. After some discussions, with tech pros and asus support I was almost sure these modules were not compatible with mobo. Luckily this was not true and after latency change I managed to boot up system and to test modules and came to the conclusion that one of them is dead.

Therefore, Maximus iv extreme z is compatible with Kingstone Hyprex Fury 8Gb modules in my case.